# No view found for id 0x7f0a000e for fragment SettingsFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android and due help from fellow SOians, I am able to proceed well. I am implementing AppBar items for navigating to respective fragments from MainActivity. The following code is part of MainActivity.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up buttonAction, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Fragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.SettingsFragment, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.action_kyc:
                // go to kycfragment
                break;
            case R.id.action_about:
                // go to aboutfragment
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I am getting Illegal Argument Exception "No view found for id 0x7f0a000e for fragment SettingsFragment"

Browsed a lot here in SO as well as outside. None of them helped me.

Please let me know what is causing the error and how to fix it.

The stack extract is below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ptimer, PID: 7759
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a000e (com.example.ptimer:id/SettingsFragment) for fragment SettingsFragment{5c8b099} (86b09f6f-49b4-470e-9753-e5acd603164c id=0x7f0a000e)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7759 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does your `MainActivity` XML layout look like?
Citing your code:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.SettingsFragment, fragment);
```

Your problem is most likely that there is no view with id `SettingsFragment` in your layout.

The first argument given to `replace` should point to the fragment container in your layout file. E.g. if your layout includes:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.example.ExampleFragment" />
```

Then it would be `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);`
See also https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add and https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#add-remove

Depending on your use case, you could also open your settings in a new activity instead of replacing a fragment inside the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I am getting the same type of error. I understood from your statement that ```fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.SettingsFragment, fragment);``` should be read as ```fragmentTransaction.replace("id of the current fragment to be replaced", "destination fragment that is to be displayed");``` . When the app is launched, launcher fragment is displayed. Hence I included Launcher Fragment here. But still I am getting the same error --No view found for id 0x7f0a0006 (com.example.ptimer:id/LauncherFragment) for fragment SettingsFragment.

Comment: No, you need the id of the fragment container, not of the current fragment. If that info is not sufficient for you you will need to add your layout file to your question

Comment: This solved my problem beautifully. Thanks a lot. Sure that I will coming back to SO again and again for my questions. Nice forum.

Comment: I see UP arrow is missing after navigating to the new fragment from launcher fragment. Also when back button is pressed, the launcher fragment is blank. Is there some more changes to the code required  to set these correct?

Comment: As per Android documentation both fragmentTransaction.setReorderingAllowed(true) and fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null) have not helped either. Still getting blank screen upon pressing back button.

Comment: Hey. Maybe this helps: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#perform But this is not related to the question you asked here. If you require help please open a new question and I'm sure somebody will be happy to help.